# Carousel bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Someone can help me?I'm testing the bootstrap carousel but it doesn't work. Specifically: the previuos/next buttons don't work and the carousel doesn't slide to the next slide. this is my page's code but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Title</title>

<!-- META -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!-- META -->

<!-- CSS -->
<link href="css/stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- CSS -->  

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- JS -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any JS errors in your console?

Comment: You either need to initialize the carousel with `data-ride="carousel"` attribute on the `#myCarousel` div.  Or initialize it explicitly in code: `$('.carousel').carousel()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you called the Carousel with the below JS?

```
    $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

Try putting the link/script at the top:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

These are embeded links and not from your root file. you can use yours but place them at the top and see if that helps.

Comment: Where I should include the script?

Comment: Either at the bottom of the page before the </body> tag (wrapped with script tags) or in a custom.js file if you are using one.

Comment: But isn't it include in bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: Editied my answer. I had similar problems once and moving the link/script files to the top of the page seem to call it. try that.

Comment: ok perfect now it works!!! thanks a lot!!! can you explain me what these scripts are ? at least I know for next time

Comment: Please tick as correct answer. These scrips are the Jquery library and the bootstrap.js library. They just needed to be at the top of the document instead of the bottom. That's all. I had same issue.

Comment: then I can remove the script before </body> tag? because in this way this scripts are included 2 times. in the head and at the bottom of my page

Comment: Yes you can remove them from there now.

Comment: No probs dude. Bugged the hell out of me when I had this problem few months back. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your first stylesheet entry is correct. Is it supposed to be stile.css?

You should include the following stylesheet (making sure it is in your stylesheet folder)

```
<link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I use the carousel slider in one of my sites. Your code seems to be missing a few details. The first div should be appended with data-ride="carousel">
My second div includes role="listbox"> and your doesn't. I have included my code for your information. I hope this helps.

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="images/Dock1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>If you have a web site it needs to be responsive and &quot;mobile
            friendly&quot; </h1>
          <p> </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://donfiler.us" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="images/Forest1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1> Revamp your website usability with HTML to WordPress Conversion Services </h1>
          <p></p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://donfiler.us" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="images/Tree1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Contact Us Today to Get Started on Your New Site </h1>
          <p> </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://donfiler.us/portfolio.html" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: the first stylesheet is my css. I tried to make the changes but the result is the same.