# Carousel don't work

Tags: carousel

I'm just learning some HTML+CSS and today I created a carousel using Bootstrap 4. For some reason it seems not to work. It actually doesn't trigger any action when i press the buttons, neither it switches the slides automatically.

Can anyone please give me some help?
thank you in advance

Please see attached code:

```
<div class="row slider">
        <div class="col mt-3">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="slider" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li> 
                    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">                                                  
                        <img  src="img/segunda.jpg" alt="Slide #1" class="d-block img-fluid">                               
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">                             
                        <img  src="img/primera.jpg" alt="Slide #2" class="d-block img-fluid">
                    </div>                          
                </div>

                <a href="#slider" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                </a>

                <a href="#slider" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
                </a>                                                            
            </div>                  
        </div>
```

Comment: No JavaScript involved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carousel bootstrap doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803549/carousel-bootstrap-doesnt-work)

Comment: No, only html with bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include javascript, for example:

`$('.slider').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})`